# Webpack 2 workflow how do I test my production files and how do I upload?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack 2 Workflow - just started Webpack 2.

My package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server",
"dev": "webpack -d —watch ",
"prod": "webpack -p"
},
```

When I run `npm run prod` it writes my files to dist. But how do I view those files. When I run `webpack-dev-server` those aren’t my dist files. It's some temporary inbetween state.

Should I run another node server as well? I should test my dist files correct? Or should I trust that what I see in the webpack-dev-server is what I will get in my dist directory?

My follow up question is how should I upload my files to the hosting server?

The way I upload my files to production is I `git push` my entire project to bitbucket. And then I logged into my hosting server through terminal and `git pull` from bitbucket.

Should I do the same thing? With a dedicated dist folder. Should I make a separate repo for the dist so I push only that? Or should I use SSH and just push that folder? What is best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not put generated files under version control. Use `rsync` or `scp` to push the folder. To view the result of the build, yes you'll need to run something locally to serve them from that folder. Depending on how your app operates, you may be able to open the index page directly in your browser.